# How can I fix a problem with transferring ERC721 by approved contract?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, transferfrom

**Hey everyone**

I'm new to NFT development and developing an ERC721 token for property ownership and marketplace. I implemented two functions to enable a user to put their token on sale for another user and approve the contract and when the other user has paid for it he receives the token and the first user receives the paid ETH. but I get `ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved` because the `transferFrom()` is called by the second user's address, not the contract address.

How can I call the `transferFrom()` by the contract address? What is the best thing to do in this case?

Here are my functions:

```
function submitSale(address buyer, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        if (!_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId)) {
            revert notTokenOwnerOrApproved();
        }
        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId] = price;
        approve(address(this), tokenId);
        console.log("Sale submited successfuly");
    }

    function payForToken(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != msg.sender) {
            revert tokenNotForSaleForThisAddress();
        }
        if (msg.value < tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId]) {
            revert paidAmountIsNotEnough();
        }

        (bool paid, ) = ownerOf(tokenId).call{value: msg.value}("");
        if (paid) {
            TransferFrom(ownerOf(tokenId), msg.sender, tokenId);
            delete tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId];
            delete tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId];
        } else {
            revert();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways you can implement a mechanism to buy and sell NFTs that would fit your needs.

#### The Problem

**Note, this problem assumes the ERC721 and the marketplace contract are two seperate contracts, if they are both contained into one contract with inheritance, then this issue isn't present.**

Your implementation appears to correctly use `transferFrom()`, the issue of "*transferFrom() is called by the second user's address, not the contract address.*" isn't an issue since `transferFrom()` is actually being called by the contract address not the second user like you thought.

To see this visually, take these example contracts:

```js
contract A {

function bar(address b) public view returns(address, address ) {
    return (msg.sender, B(b).foo());
}

}


contract B {
    function foo() public view returns(address caller) {
        caller = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

When you call `bar()` with contract B's address, you will get returned two different addresses. The first address is `msg.sender` of the function, (the user's address in your case), and the second address is the `msg.sender` of `contract B`'s `foo()` function, which is `contract A` since that is who directly called `foo()`.

[image]

This means in your example, when you call `transferFrom()`, the `msg.sender` isn't your "second user", but instead your contract is.

You can test this by copy and pasting the code into Remix, if you change the `msg.sender` in `contract B` to `tx.origin`, you will get returned the same address twice when you call `bar()`. (*Note, tx.origin is being depreciated and is not recommended to use in production*)

[image]

Now back to your issue, since it isn't being caused by a difference in addresses when calling `transferFrom()`, you may have figured out that your issue is actually occuring when you call `approve()`.

Using the same logic as I've displayed above, when you are calling `approve(address(this), tokenId);`, you are approving your contract to spend a token on behalf of itself.

Since `approve()` uses `msg.sender`, your user's will have to call this function prior to interacting with your contract. When you use a frontend to transfer a token or an NFT, usually without knowing it, you are signing an initial transaction to approve the contract.

This is why you may have to sign multiple transactions in order to make a single transfer.

### The Solution

**Note, this solution assumes the ERC721 and the marketplace contract are two seperate contracts**

The easiest solution to minimize code refactoring would be to simply remove `approve()` from inside your `submitSale()` function like so:

```js
function submitSale(address buyer, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        if (!_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId)) {
            revert notTokenOwnerOrApproved();
        }
        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId] = price;
        console.log("Sale submited successfuly");
    }
```

You would then just need to communicate to your users that they will have to `approve()` your contract to transfer the NFT on their behalf.

Of course, there are other, more complex, approaches you can take if this doesn't seem desirable to you:

### Alt Problem

**This problem assumes the NFT and marketplace contract are the same contract using inheritance.**

For this example assume the seller is **Alice** and the buyer is **Bob**.

When **Alice** calls `submitSale()`, she is approving your contract for her NFT:

```js
function submitSale(address buyer, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        if (!_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId)) {
            revert notTokenOwnerOrApproved();
        }
        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId] = price;
        approve(address(this), tokenId);
        console.log("Sale submited successfuly");
    }
```

And then when **Bob** goes to buy the NFT, he is trying to `transferFrom()` the token, but this will always fail since **Bob** is never actually approved:

```js
function payForToken(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != msg.sender) {
            revert tokenNotForSaleForThisAddress();
        }
        if (msg.value < tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId]) {
            revert paidAmountIsNotEnough();
        }

        (bool paid, ) = ownerOf(tokenId).call{value: msg.value}("");
        if (paid) {
            TransferFrom(ownerOf(tokenId), msg.sender, tokenId);
            delete tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId];
            delete tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId];
        } else {
            revert();
        }
    }
```

By calling `getApproved()` on your Sepolia deployed contract, you can see the only person approved for `tokenId` 0, is the contract itself:

[image]

[image]

### Alt Solution 1

**Note, this solution assumes the ERC721 and the marketplace contract are the same contract**

*This solution is not ideal since it requires your users to create an additional transaction*

Keeping it as close to your existing code as possible:

```
function submitSale(
        address buyer,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
    ) public onlyTokenOwner(tokenId) {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != address(0)) {
            revert alreadyOnSale();
        }
        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdToPrice[tokenId] = price;
        console.log("Sale submited successfuly");

    }

    function payForToken(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != msg.sender) {
            revert tokenNotForSaleForThisAddress();
        }
        if (msg.value < tokenIdToPrice[tokenId]) {
            revert paidAmountIsNotEnough();
        }
        bool paid = msg.value >= tokenIdToPrice[tokenId];
        if (!paid) {
            revert();
        } 
    }

function finalizeSale(uint tokenId) public onlyTokenOwner(tokenId) {
        (bool paid, ) = msg.sender.call{value: tokenIdToPrice[tokenId]}("");
        if(paid) {
        transferFrom(msg.sender, tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId], tokenId);
        delete tokenIdToPrice[tokenId];
        delete tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId];
        }
    }
```

This solution adds a new function `finalizeSale()` that is called by the user selling an NFT. This way `transferFrom()` is being called by someone who is allowed to transfer the token. The `buyer` sends the money to the contract during `payForToken()`, which means you'll likely want to add a function to cancel the buy and return the funds to the `buyer` if they change their mind about purchasing the NFT for any reason.

### Alt Solution 2

**Note this assumes the ERC721 and the marketplace contract are both the same contract.**

This method also tries to keep the code as similar to your existing logic as possible, but without creating an additional function.
To do so we can remove the first `approve()` since it's not being used anyway, and then to `transferFrom()` the NFT we can use **Open Zeppelin**'s internal `_transfer()` function to bypass any `msg.sender` checks:

```
 function submitSale(
        address buyer,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
    ) public onlyTokenOwner(tokenId) {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != address(0)) {
            revert alreadyOnSale();
        }
        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdToPrice[tokenId] = price;
        console.log("Sale submited successfuly");

    }
function payForToken(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        if (tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] != msg.sender) {
            revert tokenNotForSaleForThisAddress();
        }
        if (msg.value < tokenIdToPrice[tokenId]) {
            revert paidAmountIsNotEnough();
        }
       ( bool paid,) = tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId].call{value: msg.value}("");
        if (paid) {
            _transfer(ownerOf(tokenId), msg.sender, tokenId);
        } else {
            revert();
        }
    }
```

Please note that using the internal functions can be potentially dangerous so it is important to test any surrounding conditionals to ensure that the `_transfer()` call is only made when it makes sense to do so.

### Alt Solution 3 - ERC6105

This solution uses the standardized **EIP 6105** to *list* items for sale until an `expires` timestamp as well as allowing the NFT holder the choice of currency to receive. You can find a reference contract ready to be thrown into Remix at the [bottom of the EIP page](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6105#reference-implementation).

Here are the **EIP-6105** versions of the functions you've been using:

```
function listItem (
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 salePrice,
    uint64 expires,
    address supportedToken,
    uint256 historicalPrice
    ) public virtual{
    address tokenOwner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    if(salePrice <= 0) {
        revert SalePriceCannotBeZero();
    }
    if(expires < block.timestamp) {
        revert InvalidExpiresTimestamp();
    }
    if(!_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId)) {
        revert CallerIsntOwnerNorApproved();
    }
    _listings[tokenId] = Listing(salePrice, expires, supportedToken, historicalPrice);
    emit UpdateListing(tokenId, tokenOwner, salePrice, expires, supportedToken, historicalPrice);
  }
```

This `listItem()` function is the equivalent of your `submitSale()` except this allows anyone who pays the price to purchase it, you can obviously alter the logic to fit your desired application.

Here is the `buyItem()` function which is the equivalent of your `payForToken()` function:

```
  function buyItem(uint256 tokenId, uint256 salePrice, address supportedToken) external nonReentrant payable virtual{
    address tokenOwner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    address buyer = msg.sender;
    uint256 historicalPrice = _listings[tokenId].historicalPrice;

    if(salePrice != _listings[tokenId].salePrice) {
        revert InconsistentSalePrice();
    }
    if(supportedToken != _listings[tokenId].supportedToken) {
        revert InconsistentTokens();
    }
    if(!_isForSale(tokenId)) {
        revert InvalidListing();
    }

    /// @dev Handle royalties
    (address royaltyRecipient, uint256 royalties) = _calculateRoyalties(tokenId, salePrice, historicalPrice);

    uint256 payment = salePrice - royalties;
    if(supportedToken == address(0)){
        if(msg.value != salePrice) {
           revert IncorrectValueSent();
        }
        _processSupportedTokenPayment(royalties, buyer, royaltyRecipient, address(0));
        _processSupportedTokenPayment(payment, buyer, tokenOwner, address(0));
    }
    else{
        uint256 num = IERC20(supportedToken).allowance(buyer, address(this));
        if(num < salePrice) {
            revert InsufficientAllowance();
        }
        _processSupportedTokenPayment(royalties, buyer, royaltyRecipient, supportedToken);
        _processSupportedTokenPayment(payment, buyer, tokenOwner, supportedToken);
    }
    _transfer(tokenOwner, buyer, tokenId);
    emit Purchased(tokenId, tokenOwner, buyer, salePrice, supportedToken, royalties);
  }
```

Comment: This is the place where everyone gets stuck :) Even I was lol

Comment: @ZartajAfser so how did you solve it?

Comment: @RohanNero first of all, thank you for this complete answer, I appreciate it. I read your answer and tested the code you wrote. you are right about the addresses in this case but in your example, functions are in two contracts In my case, I'm using functions from one contract and if you put bar and foo functions in one contract you'll only get the user's address returned and you won't see the contract address.

Comment: @RohanNero I tested my contract on sepolia to be sure, and it's the same. I called the submitSale() successfully and approved the contract with no problem from the token owner account and then called getApproved() and it returned the contract address ,but when i call the payForToken() from the buyer address it reverts. you can check it on etherscan . here is the the address : https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xcdcac0f2ad12b4fc0ddb5b7911ed1cdf1e7972d4

Comment: @emtothed I misunderstood, if the ERC721 and the "market" contract are both the same contract, then `msg.sender` remains constant. This means calling `approve()` is doing nothing for you since the `transferFrom()` is called in the context of the `buyer`.  For example, if Alice approves the contract for `tokenId` 0, and then Bob tries to call `payForToken()`, `transferFrom()` will always fail because Bob was never approved to transfer the token, only the contract was. I'll add some alternative solutions in my answer body to fix this issue.

Comment: @RohanNero dear Rohan I read your alt solution, thank you so much for that, I prefer to keep the sale process in two steps and transfer the token immediately after the second user has paid for it (it's more satisfying for the buyer :D). in my case since I'm checking the buyer's address at the beginning of the payForToke(), isn't it safe to use the internal transfer function? if it's not, isn't there any other solution but to 3-step solution or splitting the code in two contracts? isn't there any way to call transferFrom() with the contract address?

Comment: @RohanNero and what is the standard way in this case? Is separating the token contract from the market contract the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: @emtothed I finished adding another solution that I think best fits your needs, just please make sure that whenever you use internal functions you make sure the call can only be made if your desired conditions are met, in your case it looks like you've already taken care of this. Also, [ERC-6105](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6105) attempts to standardize "marketplace functionality" for [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) tokens so you may want to check it out.

Comment: @emtothed And I don't think there really is a "*most appropriate*" way to do this, I think whether you separate the token contract from the marketplace contract or not is merely an opinionated design choice, so you should pick the one that you like best and you think makes the most sense for your project. I mistakenly assumed the contracts were two separate contracts when I originally read your question which is why I initially answered in that context, I left those solutions in my answer body just in case other developers in the future choose to design their contract in that way.

Comment: @emtothed if you'd like, I can add a third alt solution that uses [ERC-6105](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6105).

Comment: @RohanNero thank you so much for everything. I'll check the ERC-6105. I have a final question. please consider the auction part for answering the question too. I'm going to implement some kind of a stable coin as a complementary project to this project too. now my question is, how good do you think this project is in terms of finding a job? and how much more should I improve in your opinion? You can find the completed contract here: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x435d0c1ead8eb53b2942299c8e9062450da5e2f3

Comment: @RohanNero Yes, it would be awesome to see your ERC-6105 solution.

Comment: @emtothed That's outside my knowledge boundaries, to be honest with you, however, in my opinion, it is a great start and once you finish it, it could absolutely aid you in finding a job. Always remember to write good tests for all your smart contracts, this will help you learn while making your contracts more secure. P.S. I've added **Alt Solution 3** that uses **EIP-6105**.

Comment: @RohanNero thank you so much for everything, my friend. you really helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Good to see you're delving into NFT development and Solidity. Your problem seems to stem from a misunderstanding in how the `transferFrom()` function is utilized in the context of ERC721 tokens.

The `transferFrom()` function is meant to be called by whomever currently has approval. In your case, if you approved the contract itself (which means giving the right to transfer ownership), then the function should not be called via user but rather via another function within the contract that does the required procedure.

Here's how you can do it:

```
function submitSale(address buyer, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved");

        tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] = buyer;
        tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId] = price;

        approve(address(this), tokenId);
    }

    function payForToken(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        require(tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId] == msg.sender, "This token is not on sale for this address");
        require(msg.value >= tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId], "Payment is not sufficient");

        _transferFrom(ownerOf(tokenId), msg.sender, tokenId);

        (bool paid, ) = ownerOf(tokenId).call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(paid, "Payment failed");

        delete tokenIdToBuyer[tokenId];
        delete tokenIdtoPrice[tokenId];        
    }
```

Take note in the changes above, I have implemented the following modifications:

1. **Replaced** standard `revert` statements with `require`. It performs the same task but allows you to include a human-readable error message which will help in debugging.
2. Instead of externally calling `transferFrom()`, let's call it internally with `_transferFrom()`.
3. The internal `_transferFrom()` is called by `payForToken()`, which would be executed by the contract, thus getting rid of your issue.

Remember that you need to have a function `_transferFrom()` inside your contract which directly calls `ERC721._transferFrom()`. If it's not there, you'll have to add it as per OpenZeppelin's ERC721 contract:

```
function _transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer of token that is not own");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner
        _approve(address(0), tokenId);

        _balances[from] -= 1;
        _balances[to] += 1;

        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

I hope this helps! Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: hey dear Dream Ninja, I fixed the issue using your guidance, thank you. there was the internal function that you mentioned but its name was _transfer()and it worked, but I can't understand why the internal function is called by contract address and the public one is called by the user's address.

Comment: and about require, I prefer much more to use it instead of revert(), but MR. Patrick Collins recommends using revert since it's more gas efficient , let me know your opinion about this.

Comment: @emtothed, you are correct, using custom errors combined with `revert` is more gas efficient than traditional `require`.

Comment: @emtothed Using the internal `_transferFrom()` may seem to be solving your issue, but it is actually just creating a potential exploit. The internal function bypasses `msg.sender` checks and transfers the token "no questions asked". You definitely want to use the external/public `transferFrom()` to ensure the user is allowed to transfer the token. I've added an additional answer that explains your problem.

Comment: @DreamNinja, don't let this discourage you from helping more people, you formatted and styled your question perfectly! I look forward to seeing your name around!